# is there a direct way to solve a set of four equations with four symbols where there is a conjugate of one in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

So I have four symbols for a set of four equations in SymPy. I also have the conjugate of one of the symbols. Solution is given as an empty list, while I expect values for the symbols.

'z', 'k', 'l', and 'm', where we also have the conjugate of k and we have the set of equations eq2, eq3, eq4, and eq5.

```
from sympy import Symbol, solve, I, conjugate

z = Symbol('z')
k = Symbol('k')
l = Symbol('l')
m = Symbol('m')

gamma = 0.01
Om = 8
kappa = 1e4
N = 1e2
w = 10

eq2 = -(w+ gamma)*(z-1) + I*Om*(k - conjugate(k))
eq3 = -((w+gamma)*0.5 + kappa*0.5)*k + I*Om*0.5*(m*z + (z+1)*0.5)
eq4 = -(w+ gamma)*l + (Om*z/ (2*I)) * (k - conjugate(k))
eq5 = -kappa*m + (N*Om/(2*I))*(k - conjugate(k))

solution = solve([eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5], [z, k, l, m], dict= True)
```

As a result we obtain an empty list,

```
print(solution)
[]
```

and this is the first time I work with SymPy, so couldn't not figure what exactly could be the issue here as the documentation was not so helpful. If there is a way to solve this directly with SymPy or if the equations should be adjusted?

Comment: Please include the imports, symbol definitions, and constant definitions so we can run this code.

Comment: Also, solve syntax error. We don't know what `w` is (neither an unknown, nor a constant). And we don't know what you mean by `+ + kappa*0.5` or `w+gamma+`

Comment: The `m*z` term in `eq3` makes the equations nonlinear. Also `conjugate` is not algebraically linear.

Comment: @chrslg you're right I did not notice that, I fixed it now

Comment: @jared I modified and included the complete code

Comment: You should split the equations and in particular `k` into real and imaginary parts but that requires specifying which of the parameters or unknowns is supposed to be real or not.

Comment: This system of equations does not have any solution which is why solve returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

If SymPy is unable to find an explicit solution, it returns an empty list as you observed. Means that the eqn may require numerical methods or further analysis to find approximate solutions.

If you need to find numerical solution, you can use 'nsolve' provided by SymPy.

```
from sympy import Symbol, lambdify, I, conjugate
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

z = Symbol('z')
k = Symbol('k')
l = Symbol('l')
m = Symbol('m')

gamma = 0.01
Om = 8
kappa = 1e4
N = 1e2
w = 10

eq2 = -(w + gamma)*(z - 1) + I*Om*(k - conjugate(k))
eq3 = -((w + gamma)*0.5 + kappa*0.5)*k + I*Om*0.5*(m*z + (z + 1)*0.5)
eq4 = -(w + gamma)*l + (Om*z / (2*I)) * (k - conjugate(k))
eq5 = -kappa*m + (N*Om/(2*I))*(k - conjugate(k))

eq2_func = lambdify((z, k), eq2)
eq3_func = lambdify((z, k, m), eq3)
eq4_func = lambdify((z, k, l), eq4)
eq5_func = lambdify((k, m), eq5)

def equations(vars):
    z, k, l, m = vars
    eq1 = eq2_func(z, k)
    eq2 = eq3_func(z, k, m)
    eq3 = eq4_func(z, k, l)
    eq4 = eq5_func(k, m)
    return [eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4]

solution = fsolve(equations, [1, 1, 1, 1])
print(solution)
```

Comment: yes I did check this, the issue is that with nsolve now I get the following error: NameError: name 'Derivative' is not defined

Comment: try the updated code. The equations are converted into numerical functions using lambdify from SymPy. The equations function is defined to encapsulate the system of equations. Then, fsolve from SciPy's optimization module is used to find the numerical solution.

Comment: thank you @Aravind, my concern is that in this case the accuracy of the solution is dependent on the estimate provided for fsolve?

Comment: If there is more than one solution then which you find will depend on your initial guess. It will be accurate but different than another solution. e.g. guessing near 1 for `x**2 -1` will give solution 1 while guessing near -1 will give solution -1.